# how to update row = NULL when there is no match

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have 2 Tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #targetTable(id int,date datetime,name varchar(50));
CREATE TABLE #sourceTable(id int,date datetime,name varchar(50));
INSERT INTO #targetTable  values(1,'1905-07-08 00:00:00.000','John');
INSERT INTO #targetTable values(2,'1905-07-08 00:00:00.000','Albrt');
INSERT INTO #targetTable  values(3,'1905-07-08 00:00:00.000','Roy');

INSERT INTO #sourceTable values(1,'1905-07-09 00:00:00.000','jame');
```

i want to update the Target Table, when not match then update Name Column of Target with NULL. i would like to have this Result:

```
id   date                     name
1   1905-07-09 00:00:00.000    jame
2   1905-07-09 00:00:00.000    null
3   1905-07-09 00:00:00.000    null
```

my test Query doesn't work: Error: UPDATE IS NOT ALLOWED IN THE WHEN NOT MATCHED. is there anyway to edit the query to get the Results?

```
merge into #targetTable a 
using #sourceTable b on a.id=b.id 
when matched and b.date > a.date then
   update 
   set a.name=b.name,a.date=b.date 
when not matched by Target then 
   update a.date=b.date and a.name = null
```

---

it shows me Error. Can you please help me how to get the Result?

Comment: Put your query in your question, don't state in your question it's in a comment. the comments is the wrong place, you can't format a query there (making in an unreadble mess I'm afraid).

Comment: If you get an error, post the error message.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: why is it not ok to use a,b? Larnu

Comment: Have you read the link @Phh?

Comment: @Phh - Makes it more difficult for other developers to immediately spot what table it refers to. (I do it all the time myself as well, though).

Comment: What's worse, @SchmitzIT , is that you will often see people refer to the table `contact` as `a`, and the table `application` as `c` (which is confusing enough, contact starts with c, and application with a), but then in a different query `contact` is `b` and `application` is `a`! It's not even consistent. An alias should make it easy to be able to identify what object it is referring to, be consistent, while also making making the code succinct.

Comment: @Lamu - I mostly do datawarehousing, and typically use whatever table supplies the primary data (I.e. the fact) as a, then dimensions I need to query from become b, c, d, e in the order I add them. Works for me, but you're right, I'd not use that syntax when putting things into the actual environment where my colleagues would have to deal with my lazy code.

Comment: `RN` @SchmitzIT (or is it SchirnitzlT? :))

Comment: @Larnu - Oops. I misspelled your nick, too. It's SchmitzIT (My last name, plus IT because I do geek stuff). What's RN mean, by the way?

Comment: I was letting you know you had misspelled my name @SchmitzIT ;) hence why i said *"or is it SchirnitzlT?"*, i exchanged the m for rn (the reverse of what you had done with my name/alias :) ).

Comment: `update a.date=b.date and a.name = null` - if there is no match, how would you expect to `update` that "nothingness"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the question and all the comments what you really want is

- `UPDATE` the row based upon the `id` with both the `date` and `name` but set the `name` to `NULL` when there is no match and set the `date` to the max date at the same time with that condition.
- `UPDATE` with new values (`name`,`date`) when there is a match on `id`

I used a table variable for simplicity here but the concept is the
   same.

Given the table and data this produces:

```
DECLARE  @targetTable TABLE (id int,date datetime,name varchar(50));
DECLARE  @sourceTable TABLE (id int,date datetime,name varchar(50));
INSERT INTO @targetTable  
VALUES
(1,'1905-07-08 00:00:00.000','John'),
(2,'1905-07-08 00:00:00.000','Albrt'),
(3,'1905-07-08 00:00:00.000','Roy');

INSERT INTO @sourceTable values(1,'1905-07-09 00:00:00.000','jame');

SELECT  id,date,name  FROM @targetTable;
SELECT  id,date,name  FROM @sourceTable;

id  date    name
1   1905-07-08 00:00:00.000 John
2   1905-07-08 00:00:00.000 Albrt
3   1905-07-08 00:00:00.000 Roy

id  date    name
1   1905-07-09 00:00:00.000 jame
```

What you desire is basically the same as this select statement:

```
SELECT 
    t.id,
    CASE 
        WHEN s.id IS NOT NULL THEN s.[date]
        ELSE (SELECT MAX([date]) FROM @sourceTable )
    END AS [date],
    CASE 
        WHEN s.id IS NULL THEN NULL
        ELSE s.name
    END AS [name]
FROM @targetTable AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN  @sourceTable AS s
    ON t.id = s.id;
```

SO to do that, we can incorporate that into an update:

```
UPDATE @targetTable
    SET [date] = CASE 
        WHEN s.id IS NOT NULL THEN s.[date]
        ELSE (SELECT MAX([date]) FROM @sourceTable )
    END,
    [name] = CASE 
        WHEN s.id IS NULL THEN NULL
        ELSE s.name
    END
FROM @targetTable AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN  @sourceTable AS s
    ON t.id = s.id;
```

Final output

```
SELECT id,date,name  FROM @targetTable;

id  date                    name
1   1905-07-09 00:00:00.000 jame
2   1905-07-09 00:00:00.000 NULL
3   1905-07-09 00:00:00.000 NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

No offense but your query has whole a lot of syntax issues.

Secondly, a merge statement cannot update values in the target table when not matched. You should try inserting instead.

Here is a example:

```
MERGE INTO #targetTable a 
USING #sourceTable b 
ON a.id=b.id 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET 
        a.name=b.name,
        a.date=b.date 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT  
    (
        id,
        date,
        name
    )
    VALUES 
    (
        b.id,
        b.date,
        null as name
    )
```

Comment: Problem with insert is that there is extra ROWs which i don't need

Comment: The insert statement here is in not matched block, so it will only insert the records that are not present in the target table but exists in the source table. I believe this is what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks Pratik, i have tested your Query but it doesn't show what i want

Answer (score 0):

I would use `APPLY`  :

```
UPDATE t
       SET t.name = s.name, 
           t.date = s.date
FROM #targetTable t OUTER APPLY
     ( SELECT TOP (1) s.*
       FROM #sourceTable s
       WHERE s.id = t.id
     ) s;
```

Your merge has Source value also :

```
merge #targetTable a 
using #sourceTable b 
      on a.id=b.id 
when matched  
     then update 
         set a.name = b.name, a.date= b.date 
when not matched by SOURCE  
     then update 
          set a.name = null;
```

Comment: Thanks Sharma, but it doesn't works. it update Date of Target to NULL.

Comment: @Phh. . . I have provided two approaches, second approach should solve your problem.

Comment: Thankyou. but it give us 2 different Dates. i want only 1 Date

Answer (score 0):

You need `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE`, so something like:

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
THEN UPDATE 
        SET a.name = NULL
```

Comment: Invalid SQL syntax for certain databases. When not matched, you can only do insert.

Comment: The question is tagged [sql-server], and it's certainly valid syntax and a possible operation in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

So if I get your problem, you simply want to update the name in table #targetTable if there is no matching row in #sourceTable.

You don't need a `MERGE` statement to accomplish this.

```
UPDATE #targetTable
SET 
    [name] = COALESCE([source].name, NULL)
    , date = [source_date].maxDate
FROM 
    #targetTable AS [target]
    LEFT JOIN #sourceTable AS [source] ON [target].id = [source].id
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT max(date) AS maxDate FROM #sourcetable) AS [source_date] 
WHERE 
    [source].id IS NULL
```

This yields the following output:

[image]

Comment: thanks schmitz. i got problem with the date column of Target. it should be replaced by date from Source. it should shows '1905-07-09 00:00:00.000 '

Comment: @Phh - You're welcome. If this answered your question, please remember to mark it as such. This helps future visitors to the question figure out what to do to resolve the issue.

Comment: @Phh - Is that only for row 1? (The one that is matched). There's no way to grab a date from the source if there's no corresponding row for the ids that don't exist in the source.

Comment: thanks you. your query is not bad. but it still show old Date. i want to have new Date with  '1905-07-09 00:00:00.000 '

Comment: @Phh - Check my updated query. This will apply the maximum date existing in the source, so you'd only be able to stuff a single date in the date column. It works in this particular case, but with larger datasets where you might want to retain matched dates, things might get more complex. However, we lack the information to help you further with that kind of a challenge.

Comment: Thanks SchmitzIT, Your Query help me alot with the hardest part on the UPDATE, i can edit it later to use it in my Database

Comment: Result does not match the desired output here